# counting matching elements of two vectors but not including repeated elements in the count

Tags: r, performance, optimization, pattern-matching, match

I've search a lot in this forum. However, I didn't found a similar problem as the one I'm facing.

My question is:
I have two vectors
`x <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,6,7,8)` and `z <- c(1,1,2,4,5,5,5)`

I need to count the number of times **x** or **z** appears in each other including if they are repeated or not.

The answer for this problem should be **4** because :
There are ***two* number 1**, ***one* number 2**, and ***one* number 4** in each vector.

Functions like **match()** don't help since they will return the answer of repeated for non repeated numbers. Using **unique()** will also alter the final answer from **4** to **3**

What I came up with was a loop that every time it found one number in the other, it would remove from the list so it won't be counted again.
The loop works fine for this size of this example; however, searching for larger vectors numerous times makes my loop inefficient and too slow for my purposes.

```
system.time({
    for(n in 1:1000){
        x <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,6,7,8)
        z <- c(1,1,2,4,5,5,5)
        score <- 0
        for(s in spectrum){
            if(s %in% sequence){
                sequence <- sequence[-which(sequence==s)[1]]
                score <- score + 1
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Can someone suggest a better method?
I've tried using lapply, for short vectors it is faster, but it became slower for longer ones..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use R's vectorization to your advantage here.  There's no looping necessary.

You could use a `table` to look at the frequencies,

```
table(z[z %in% x])
# 
# 1 2 4 
# 2 1 1
```

And then take the `sum` of the table for the total

```
sum(table(z[z %in% x]))
# [1] 4
```

Comment: hi Richard your version is really simple indeed. However, the normal for loop still is 20% more efficient...  
http://prntscr.com/56gufh
I'm still looking for something with faster results...
Maybe I will have to simplify stuffs in the other pieces of my code...

Comment: it seems that for some reason, alone the code works slower; however, inside of the function your code works 25% faster than the loop.

Comment: Interesting, how big is the vector you're using?

Comment: I was doing [this exercise](https://stepic.org/lesson/The-Spectral-Convolution-Saves-the-Day-104/step/7?course=Bioinformatics-Algorithms&unit=425) in the Coursera.  
See the [extra dataset](https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/bioinformatics/data/antibiotics/convolution.txt). One of the vectors is that big, the other vector starts from 1 and goes to a size of ~20. At first my code would go fast. However, it would start to slow down to a point that it would take almost 10 minutes to finish. With your help now it takes almost 2 minutes. :D